# Diophantine approximation and Farey sequences

Tags: analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation, farey-sequences

I am self studying Apostol *Dirichlet Series and Modular Functions in Number Theory* and could not solve this question given in Chapter 7. 
Please help.

Question is – Let $ \Theta $ be an irrational number strictly between 0 and 1 .  Then $ \Theta $ lies between two consecutive Farey fractions,  say   $  { a \over  b  }   <  \Theta   < { c \over d } $.

Prove that either $ \Theta   -   { a \over b }   <  { 1 \over 2 b^2} $ or 
$ { c \over d }  -  \Theta  <   {1\over 2 d^2 } $.

Comment: Hint: to prove this statement by contradiction, you can assume that both $ \Theta   -   { a \over b }   \ge  { 1 \over 2 b^2} $ and 
$ { c \over d }  -  \Theta  \ge  {1\over 2 d^2 } $ (and of course the context $  { a \over  b  }   <  \Theta   < { c \over d } $) and try to get a contradiction with the fact that $\frac ab$ and $\frac cd$ are consecutive Farey fractions. Can you see how? Do you know any relations that consecutive Farey fractions always satisfy?

Comment: @Greg Martin  I was thinking along such lines.  Thank you